# Unable to get all records displayed in report viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

[edit:I added the data visualizer]
I have a teacher's registration where records are being input using an insert button in a SQL database as such

```
private void insertdata(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string name = name_field.Text;
                string email = email_field.Text;

                string id = id_field.Text;
                string gender;
                if (male.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    gender = "M";
                }
                else
                    gender = "F";


                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dob.Text))
                {
                    string fe = "01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM";
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(fe);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dob.Text);

                }



                var rich1 = new TextRange(this.history.Document.ContentStart, this.history.Document.ContentEnd);

                string teach_history = rich1.Text;

                var rich2 = new TextRange(this.achievement.Document.ContentStart, this.achievement.Document.ContentEnd);

                string teach_achievement = rich2.Text;

                connect();
                con.Open();


                string saved = "insert into teacher_details ([Teacher ID],Name,Gender,Email,[Date of Birth],Employment History,Achievements)values('" + id + "', '" + name + "','" + gender + "','" + email + "','" + dt + "','" + teach_history + "','" + teach_achievement + "')";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saved, con);

                cmd.ExecuteReader();

                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("record is added");
              
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error occured " + ex);
            }
```

I have id,gender,name,email,history,achievements,date of birth as my fields. I made a class for this as follows:

```
    class Teacherdetail
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string history { get; set; }
        public string acheive { get; set; }
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    }
```

in my rdlc report i used object as my dataset and selected Teacherdetail. Then I made a table as follow:
[image: teacherreport.rdlc]

i then have a button view report where I call details into the reportviewer that is called teacherreport

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
            connect();
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select [Teacher ID],Name,Gender,email,[Date of Birth],[Employment History],Achievements from teacher_details", con);

            DataTable newtab = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(newtab);
            reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";



            reportDataSource.Value = newtab;

            teacherreport.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Users\\Preeti Rawat\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\STDNT\\STDNT\\teacherreport.rdlc"; 



            teacherreport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

            teacherreport.LocalReport.Refresh();
            teacherreport.RefreshReport();
```

[image]

My problem is that id, history, name and achieve are missing.

When I debug the program, in my data visualizer it does show that the information is passing through.
[image]
but it is still not appearing when in the program. What can the problem be and how can I fix it? Thank you ^^

Comment: You've written all that and then looked at the end result. There's a problem part way through your process though. You should have written the insert and then checked it worked. You'd have then realised you had a problem with the insert.

Comment: Building a sql string with variables like that is a bad idea. Google sql injection. I recommend you look into dapper. It's a set of extension methods which make working with ado simpler and less error prone.

Comment: The insert query works. I have even used a datagrid and all of the details appears in it.

Comment: Executereader reads data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was not working was that the class names were different from the table's field name. They have to be the same. So I changed column names of my database table so that it looks like this:

Teacher_ID,Name,Gender,Email,Date_of_Birth,Employment_History,Achievements

and my class looks like this:

```
        public int Teacher_ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
        public string Employment_History { get; set; }
        public string Achievements { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, in your `insertdata`, you are calling `ExecuteReader` to insert a new record, and it's wrong. You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` to `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` actions.

Also, in :

```
string saved = "insert into teacher_details ([Teacher ID],Name,Gender,Email,[Date of Birth],Employment History,Achievements)values('" + id + "', '" + name + "','" + gender + "','" + email + "','" + dt + "','" + teach_history + "','" + teach_achievement + "')";
```

this should return a SQL error, since `Employment History` not contained by brackets `[]`.

Here is a revised version of your method. (I've tried to kept the same work).

```
var name = name_field.Text;
var name = name_field.Text;
var email = email_field.Text;
var id = id_field.Text;
var gender = male.IsChecked ? "M" : "F";
var dt = DateTime.TryParse(dob.Text, out DateTime result) ? result : new DateTime(1900,1,1); 
var teach_history = new TextRange(this.history.Document.ContentStart, this.history.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
var teach_achievement = new TextRange(this.achievement.Document.ContentStart, this.achievement.Document.ContentEnd).Text;


const string query = "INSERT INTO teacher_details([Teacher ID],Name,Gender,Email,[Date of Birth],[Employment History],Achievements) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'); ";      

var saved = string.Format(query, id, name, gender, email, dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"), teach_history, teach_achievement)

connect();
con.Open();

using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(saved, con))
{
    cmd.ExcuteNonQuery();
}

con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("record is added");
```

you should use `using` blocks on `SqlConnection` or Dispose your connection manually. Also, I suggest you start using `Entity Framework` instead for database operations.

For the report part, you need to do this :

```
var table = new DataTable();

const string query = "SELECT [Teacher ID],Name,Gender,email,[Date of Birth],[Employment History],Achievements from teacher_details";

connect();
con.Open();

var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    adapter.Fill(table);

var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("Dataset1", table);

teacherreport.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Users\\Preeti Rawat\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\STDNT\\STDNT\\teacherreport.rdlc"; 

teacherreport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();  

teacherreport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);  

teacherreport.LocalReport.Refresh();

teacherreport.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: I am getting an error that ExecuteNonquery does not have a definition. Also, I even have a data grid and all my datas are appearing there even with ExecuteReader

Comment: @preeti `ExecuteNonquery` should be `ExecuteNonQuery`. When you reading data, use `SqlDataAdapter` to fill the data into the grid.

Comment: I tried. and while the code is working, I am still not getting all my report details :/

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work :/ now no data appears nor does the column name

Comment: while the report is there. The same columns are missing :/